# Can't tag images on drone docker build: Error parsing reference: ":latest" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format

Tags: docker, drone.io

I'm trying to use drone with gitlab. Before the step of pushing the docker image to my private registry, it raise an error:

```
Successfully built 7afb99118ae2
Successfully tagged ae872a846df0d8df884e89bd3a77cacf49b8f7de:latest
+ /usr/local/bin/docker tag ae872a846df0d8df884e89bd3a77cacf49b8f7de :latest
Error parsing reference: ":latest" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format
```

My drone is drone/drone:1.0.0-rc.3

Here is my .drone.yml file

```
kind: pipeline
name: default

steps:
- name: build
  image: python:3.6
  commands:
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
  - python -m pytest app.py
  when:
    branch:
    - master
    event:
    - push
    - pull_request

- name: publish
  image: plugins/docker
  registry: registry.cn-beijing.aliyuncs.com
  repo: registry.cn-beijing.aliyuncs.com/xxx/xxx
  tags: latest
  username: 
  - from_secret: ali_username
  password:
  - from_secret: ali_password
```

And my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Shanghai /etc/localtime && echo "Asia/Shanghai" > /etc/timezone
COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt
ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

I have tried like these:

```
tags: latest
tags: 1
tags: [1, 1.1]
tags: [1, 1.1, latest]
tags:
  - latest
```

And even delete `tags` row, but nothing worked.

What's wrong with it? Thanks for any tip!

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere from your yml file `tag value` is set to empty but the `docker tag` command have `:` in command.

See the image to generate the above error.

[image]

I did not work with drone.io but there is an indentation or configuration issue in your yml file, tags under setting, so which should be like

```
kind: pipeline
name: default

steps:
- name: docker  
  image: plugins/docker
  settings:
    username: kevinbacon
    password: pa55word
    repo: foo/bar
    tags: latest
```

http://plugins.drone.io/drone-plugins/drone-docker/

Comment: Thanks, I can tag it on command line, but it didn't work on drone. And as I said, `tags: latest` had been tried.

Comment: remove the tags so it will use latest by default